# jquery change event without postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a listbox and on a particular selected value i want to display a dropdown and on selection of a value from the dropdown i want to display another dropdown.

I have achieved this using jquery but the dropdowns are displayed only after postback. How to avoid the postbacks ?

This is my jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($('#<%=under_list1.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 0) {
        $("#ddl_nature1").show();
        $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
        if ($('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'I', $('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'E') {
            $("#ddl_gross1").show();

        }
        else {
            $("#ddl_gross1").hide();

        }
    }
    else {
        $("#ddl_nature1").hide();
        $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
    }
});
```

under_list1 is my listbox id, ddl_nature1 is my first dropdown and ddl_gross1 is my second dropdown.

Comment: Post code from your code behind and from aspx page. You can set AutoPostBack to false in dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the same check on dropdownlist change. I place here the change of the dropdownlist on a common function, and call it ones the dropdownlist change, and ones when the DOM is ready (witch is the after post back).

```
$('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %>').change(function() {
  ChangeViews();
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    ChangeViews();
});

function ChangeViews()
{
    if ($('#<%=under_list1.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 0) {
        $("#ddl_nature1").show();
        $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
        if ($('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'I', $('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'E') {
            $("#ddl_gross1").show();
        }
        else {
            $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
        }
    }
    else {
        $("#ddl_nature1").hide();
        $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have to refresh the page in order to view the second dropdown on selection of a particular value from the listbox and again refresh the page to view the third dropdown on selection of a value from the second dropdown

Comment: After trying a lot i still have to repeatedly refresh the page after i select the value from the listbox in order to get the second and third dropdown.

Comment: @asifa I need the htlp part of your code to fully understand what you ask. Here I understand that you like to do that without post back.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont u use Ajax PageLoad function. As pageLoad function will be called after each PostBack.

```
   function pageLoad()
    {
      if ($('#<%=under_list1.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 0) {
            $("#ddl_nature1").show();
            $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
            if ($('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'I', $('#<%=ddl_nature.ClientID %> option:selected').val() == 'E') {
                $("#ddl_gross1").show();

            }
            else {
                $("#ddl_gross1").hide();

            }
        }
        else {
            $("#ddl_nature1").hide();
            $("#ddl_gross1").hide();
        }

}
```

Comment: i don't want to do postback. If i select a certain value say 1 from the listbox then the dropdown should be displayed and on selection of value 1 from the dropdown i want to display the third dropdown. The dropdowns are displayed properly but only on page refresh

Comment: i don't want to refresh or load the page again and again to display the corresponding dropdowns